# Can't install BeautifulSoup4 module

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to use the BeautifulSoup4 module for use with Python3/IDLE. Python 3 is installed in my Mac's /Applications folder. The preinstall of Python 2.7 is installed in my Mac's /Library folder.

Most online guides tell me to install BeautifulSoup4 using Terminal and the pip command. So I execute:

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

This installs BeautifulSoup4 into the Python 2.7 folder. When I open IDLE and execute:

```
import bs4
```

it tells me that no such module exists. When I list the modules, BeautifulSoup4 isn't there. If I try installing using a virtual environment in the Terminal, it tells me it can't find the module.

I am also generally confused about why there are two versions of Python, one in /Library and one in /Applications. Should I be trying to install Python 3 in the /Applications folder?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup`? That might help install it to the right folder :)

Comment: When I do that I get the response "no distributions at all found."

Comment: Maybe you forgot the 4, `sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 0):

If the option @jermenkoo provides isn't the solution, try importing the library like this, as the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) says:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I tried that, it just tells me "no such module as bs4" :(

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7 and 3.x has different environment, if you want to install for Python 3 use `pip3`

```
sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
# or
sudo /path/to/python3 -m pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

to use it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```